# TAB key auto fill in batch file

Tags: batch-file

i want to make something that fills in text for me.
for example, when i type this:

`stack`

and press TAB it fills it in like this:

`stackoverflow`

Answer (score 0):

You could use doskey macros I believe. The following should help:

http://ben.versionzero.org/wiki/Doskey_Macros

Comment: I looked at it and i dont really know how this would help me :/